# Git not showing current/incoming change for deleted lines, when merging branches

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to learn more about git branching / merging, having only been working with the 'master' branch all this time.

I branch out twice, and then perform a merge

[image]

Why does git only show me the new conflicting lines? I'm wondering why the removal of "Bear" is not highlighted as a change at all?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Sa7Qrs5.png]

Comment: Because it's only *supposed* to show you the conflicting lines - the ones that aren't conflicts don't need input from you.

Comment: Right.... the deletion of bear is not conflicting so that one goes away.... then the ending of the files do conflict and that's what you get.

Comment: And it _is_ highlighted if you know where to check: `git diff HEAD`, then you will see that the line is gone.

Comment: @eftshift0 Ah yes, when I call `git diff SECONDFILE THIRDFILE` I do see the deletion highlighted.

Conceptually, I still find it strange that whether I merge SECONDFILE to THIRDFILE, or vice versa, `Bear` is always deleted... What if I don't mean for it to be deleted in the merge?

Comment: But git can't know what your intent is. It can only infer what should happen from what the tips carry _and_ how they differ from the point where they split. So, common ancestor has the workd `bear` between `ant` and `cat`. Then one of the branches still holds it, the other doesn't. To git, it's _obvious_ that one of the two branches deleted it.. and given that the other branch didn't touch it, it is deleted on the resulting file.

Comment: @eftshift0 Okay! I guess the key is that it's made in comparison with the ancestor, so any non-conflicting change that is detected is interpreted as intended.

Thank you so much for your sharing!

Comment: you can use a 3-way merge tool like KDiff, it will show you all differences and you can select what you want in the merge per difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've covered some of this in comments already, but let's write it up:

- When you use `git merge`, you are actually selecting *three* commits.  Each of those three commits has a full (but read-only) snapshot of each committed file, in the form the file had at the time you (or whoever) made the commit.
- The three commits are:

  - Your current commit (`HEAD`, which is the tip of the current branch);
  - The other commit you name: `git merge somebranch` means the tip (i.e., last) commit of the branch `somebranch`; and
  - The *merge base* of these two commits.

#### Draw the commit graph to find the merge base

To find the merge base of two commits, you can:

- draw the *commit graph* and use your eyeballs; or
- use `git merge-base`, which has an algorithm to do this, and then just prints out the raw hash ID.

Your own image actually shows a bit of how the commit graph works.  I don't have a nice way to do that, so instead, I like to draw the commits like this:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

for instance.  Here the name `master` selects commit `H`, which has the snapshot in which the file you care about contains:

```
Ant
Bear
Cat
```

The name `branch1` selects commit `J`, where the file with the same name contains:

```
Ant
Bear
Cat
Deer
Elephant
Frog
```

The name `branch2` selects commit `L`, where this same file<sup>1</sup> contains:

```
Ant
Cat
Giraffe
Hippo
Iguana
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Here is a question for you to think about.  It's partly, but not purely, philosophical: *How do we know that this is the same file?*  See also [the paradox of the Ship of Theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus).

---

#### Setting up the merge

At this point you run `git checkout branch1` if needed—so that `HEAD` is attached to `branch1` and therefore commit `J` is the current commit—and then `git merge branch2`, to select commit `L` as the commit to merge.  Git now walks backwards from *both* commits, `J` and `L`, until it finds a commit that is on *both* branches.  Commits `I` and `J` are only on `branch1` and commits `K-L` are only on `branch2`.  Commit `G` is on both branches, but so is commit `H`.  So the *best* shared (common) ancestor is commit `H` (conveniently pointed-to by the name `master` in our example, but often there's no extra name and you just have to use the raw hash ID `H`.)

In order to perform the merge, Git actually looks at *every file in `H`* and then at *every file in `J`*.  In effect, Git runs `git diff --find-renames` on the two commits.  This finds the changes in your file from `H` to `J`:

```
 Ant
 Bear
 Cat
+Deer
+Elephant
+Frog
```

There are no lines deleted and three lines added starting after the last line (line 3).

Next, Git compares the file in `H` to the one in `L`, again as if by running `git diff`.  This time we have:

```
 Ant
-Bear
 Cat
+Giraffe
+Hippo
+Iguana
```

There is one line deleted, between lines 1 and 3; and then three lines added after the last line.

Note that in this situation, *you* changed the file (from `H` to `J`) and *they*—whoever they are, although "they" are just you again—also changed the file (from `H` to `L`).  This forces Git to do a full file-level merge on the file.  Had only "you" or only "they" changed the file, Git would be able to cheat: the merge result would be your or their version of that file.

#### Performing a file-level merge

Now that Git has to merge individual changes to the file, Git falls back on a line-by-line process.  Wherever you changed the file, if they did not touch the "same line(s)", Git will take *your* change.  Wherever they changed the file, if you did not touch the "same line(s)", Git will take *their* change.

Here, they deleted line 2.  You not only did not change line 2 in any way, you also did not touch its adjacent lines, 1 and 3.  "Same line" above includes abutting lines, so Git feels safe to take their change here.

On the other hand, both you and they added three lines at the end, after what was line 3 in the merge-base-commit copy.  Your change and their change therefore abut: both touch line 3.  So Git declares a *merge conflict* for this portion of the file.

When Git encounters a merge conflict, the default action—at least for text files like this one—is for Git to write, to your working tree, its best effort at combining the changes, with the conflicts surrounded by conflict-markers.  That is what you see when you open the working-tree-copy of the file for editing.

There's a handy wrinkle here though:  Git keeps *all three copies* of the three input files—the merge base, the `--ours`, and the `--theirs` files—in Git's *index*.<sup>2</sup>  This provides Git the ability to run third-party merge tools (kdiff3, vimdiff, meld, etc).  These tools usually want three or four file names:

- the merge base file;
- the `--ours` file;
- the `--theirs` file;
- and the place to write the result, perhaps with Git's merge attempt in it.

The `git mergetool` command arranges to run your chosen merge tool on all of these files, by first extracting usable (non-Git-ified) copies from the index to some temporary work area.

---

<sup>2</sup>Technically, what's in the index is not an actual copy, but rather a reference.  The commits themselves contain de-duplicated copies of the files, in a read-only, Git-only, compressed format, and there's no need to duplicate these: the index can just refer to the de-duplicated commit copies.  But you don't normally need to know about this anyway.

---

#### Your job is to complete the merge correctly

Whatever process you use—that involves a merge tool or not—your job is now to produce the *correct* merge of the three input files.  (I usually prefer just to edit Git's merge attempt directly, myself.)  You must then store that correct merge in the correct file name.  Usually all three files had the same names to start with, and the merge result goes in a file of the same name, but there are some odd corner cases with renamed files here.

Each Git commit stores a full (but de-duplicated) snapshot of *all* of the files, and a merge commit is no different.  The merge commit you will make will contain *your* copy of the file, and from here on, Git will assume that this is the *correct* way to combine those three input files.  Perhaps keeping the deleted `Bear` is correct, but perhaps it should become `Basilisk` or `Buffalo` or something.  Perhaps it's correct to add all six of the added lines, but if so, *you* must choose the correct order for these six lines.

Having written out the correct file, you can then run:

```
git add somefile
```

to tell Git: *copy the work-tree version of the updated file into your index, getting rid of the three versions taken from merge-base, `--ours`, and `--theirs`*.  If you use `git mergetool`, the mergetool command will run this `git add` for you.<sup>3</sup>  If not, you need to do this yourself.

When you have supplied the *correct* merge, you should run either:

```
git merge --continue
```

or just:

```
git commit
```

The former is easier to remember and has a small safety check: it makes sure there *is* a conflicted merge to finish, and then just runs the latter.  So in the end, they work out the same.

---

<sup>3</sup>There are some wrinkles around this as well: not all merge tools inform Git correctly whether it *should* run `git add` for you, so sometimes Git will ask you whether to run `git add` for you.

---

#### The merge result looks like this

Given:

```
          I--J   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

(I've dropped the name `master` because it is in the way), the final merge result looks like this:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- branch1 (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- branch2
```

The current branch *name* `branch1` now points to new *merge commit* `M`.  That commit points back to the previously-current commit `J` as its *first parent*.<sup>4</sup>  Merge commit `M` points back to commit `L`—the one you selected—as its *second parent*.  This is how Git records the fact that the commit *is* a merge commit, and that it merges these two sequences of commits: the fact that commit `H` was the merge base is *not* recorded directly, but is implied by the fact that running `git merge-base` on commits `J` and `L` will find commit `H` again.

Commit `M` is otherwise just like any other commit: it has a full snapshot of every file—in the form you provided, by resolving the merge conflict—plus metadata about who made it, when, and why (your log message).  To see what you did in resolving the conflict, you just have to have Git compare `J`-vs-`M`, which shows you what you brought in because of `L`, and/or compare `L`-vs-`M`, which shows you what you brought in because of `J`.

---

<sup>4</sup>The way I draw these commit graphs, it's not easy to tell which parent is the *first* parent.  The first-parent-ness is important in Git because `git log` has a `--first-parent` flag.  Using this flag, you can follow only the "main line" of commits, without viewing those brought in by merges.

The `git log --graph` command draws the graph vertically, rather than horizontally, and then always shows the *first* parent of a merge commit as the straight-down line, with the *second* parent bending out-and-to-the-right:

```
*  a merge commit
|\
* |  a commit on the main line
| *  a commit on the branch that got merged
: :
```

Other than this special `--first-parent` mode, though, it's unimportant which parent is which: the merge, after all, *combines* the changes, and you'd get the same result if you had the parents swapped around (though if you use `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs`, the swapped-around would imply swapping the `--ours` and `--theirs` commits too).